# Memory efficient way to represent shortest path?

Tags: c++, database, memory-management, graph

Say I am given the shortest path from node A to node B. The path is simply a list of edges, so a path
A->B->C, will be represented as [(A,B),(B,C)].

Currently, each node is of type **string**, a path from one node to another, say (A, B), is a **set** of string, and the path is a **list** of sets.

Now, the path consists of over 60k edges, and it must be saved to a database for later retrieval.

So obviously, I need a very nice way to represent this path in C++ such that:

1. the size of the path is significantly reduced compared to the original,
2. when retrieving the path from the database, the retrieval time is small enough.

Can anyone provide me with some insight?

Thank you.

Comment: You use the same nodes twice in the path. Can't you represent path as a `ABCD` instead of `ABBCCD`? You will gain some memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see exactly what you want, but maybe you just store your path like:

```
std::map<int, std::string> route; // int is how many edges you've already travelled (starting from 0 for the first node) and the string is the node letter you're at by that point.
```

This gives you ordered iteration of your route, and decent efficiency for operations on the map (search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to represent edges? Store whole paths in the database. And feel free to store them as strings (as @vahancho mentioned, use `ABCD` instead of `ABBCCD`). It is obvious which edges belong to this path when you look at it. And you may even use wildcards later to search, which paths contain an edge like `BC` by using `%BC%` in relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

**Memory efficiency** depends on how you can **represent** your data (**path**), if the example you have provided is the case, then you can try *Mr. vahancho suggestion*.

---

You can use `std:: unordered_map` it's fair for both **memory** and **time** complexity, or might be better to try to build your own **data structure** for storing only **useful** information, **hashing** your path string,... etc, may by wrapping `SLT` and **overloading** some functionalities.

In case of string like you provide `ABBCCD` then you may instead of store all paths as strings you can try store them as `g-trie` **data-structure** by this way you are going to reduce the **redundancy** on the **graph** **significantly** as `ABB` and `AB` paths, going to be stored as three nodes of `char` (1 **byte**),the idea is ignoring common **substructure** such (`AB`).

You can check this [paper](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/%7Epribeiro/pubs/pdf/ribeiro-acmsac2010.pdf) too.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the strings alot in the `c++` code and they are very large you might consider using a pointer or smart pointer instead. There's also the option of hashing the strings, but that will mostly be usefull for comparisons. Generally why worry about using strings in the first place, except if they are very large like text documents.

As for container, you could just use a `std::vector<std::string>`

The most efficient way of storing the shortest path of A to B in the end is just storing the end points, then only calculate the result when needed.