# shortest path of all nodes to every other nodes(Floyd–Warshall) with one condition

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, graph

Hi I have already posted a similar question but there was a misunderstanding of the problem by my side so here I post it again.

So there is a **weighted graph**, and the shortest paths of all pair of nodes are already calculated using **Floyd–Warshall** algorithm. Now I need to store all of the shortest paths in a database, because loading on the memory is not an option.

The query to the database would simply be (S,T), starting node, target node respectively, so that I can retrieve the shortest path from S to T without having to calculate it dynamically.

The problem is, I need to reduce the size of the database as much as possible. Currently all nodes are of type string, and edges are a pair of nodes, and the path is a list of edges. There are **over 60k nodes**.

1. If you think about it, some paths will definitely be a subset of another.

Check this example:

(A, D) -> (A, B, C, F, D)

(A, C) -> (A, B, C)

In these two example paths, A, B, C are duplicates. There must be an efficient way to cope with the duplicate subpaths when storing to the database.

I need to save all the shortest paths that satisfy the condition while reducing the size of the database as much as possible. I would say **maximum 40 MB**.

I am implementing this in C++. Can i get some insight please?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and you current attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: For each pair (S, T) you need to store only one connection P->T where P is the previous node in the path S -> ... -> P -> T.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572763/memory-efficient-way-to-represent-shortest-path

Comment: You only need to store the next node. (A->D) -> B. And then to find the next node, now you're at B so you look up (B->D) -> C. And then (C->D) -> F. And then (F->D) -> D. You could skip the last one if you're already storing the fact that F is connected to D. (but remember that *sometimes* the fastest way to get from X->Y *isn't* to go directly to Y even if you can)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory efficient way to represent shortest path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572763/memory-efficient-way-to-represent-shortest-path)

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov the question you linked, I posted. There was misunderstanding of the question from my side so this is a different question. So the answer is no.